# I can't find a comfortable place to sing when playing guitar

Tags: vocal-range

My vocal range is between G2 and E4, but I cant find a place on the guitar to sing comfortable. If anyone could suggest a good place to try and sing it would be great!

Comment: I actually struggled with this problem for years - sliding the capo around and never being satisfied. My solution ended up being to tune the entire guitar down a minor-third and now everything fits so much more comfortably.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - you're almost implying that you sing everything in the same key, which happens to be a m3 lower than others. How can that be? I'm sure you play different songs in different keys, so what difference will down-tuning make. Play song xyz in C? Too high for you? So play it in A instead ! Same end product - with the subtle changes of chord voicings.

Comment: @Tim - my particular problem was that with a standard-tuned guitar, in lower capo positions, my voice would be in the same tessitura as then guitar when singing in a comfortable octave, but I didn't have the range to sing entire songs with proper vocal production up the octave - I was vocally fatigued, sounded strained, and it didn't fit my voice. In order to find a good vocal placement, I'd have to put the capo up to at least 5th fret before I could sing in a comfortable tessitura, but then I don't have a big, resonant guitar sound.

Comment: @Tim - for me, shifting the entire guitar down works because now I can capo around in the lower positions, get a full guitar resonance; I can sing in the top  half of my range with nice production / resonance, and I'm not fighting tessitura with the guitar. Tuning the guitar down a m3 doesn't imply playing in the same key any more than a standard-tuned guitar implies playing everything in the same key.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - not being funny, but I've never considered the guitar to have a tessitura. That's normally reserved for certain (not all) songs. I fukly understand the guitar will sound richer when tuned lowe, although capod at fret three, I reckon it'll sound the same as a standard guitar? Please enlighten me!

Comment: @Tim - any instrument can have a tessitura; tessitura is simply where the majority of notes are in a given melody / piece. Tessitura is different than range, as it constitutes an average. Re: capo, yes you’re right, that would sound quite similar. However, I also do a lot with open strings, as well as tuning low. Sometimes I tune down to C# and sometimes I drop it all the way to B. Dropping it a whole P4 really shifts the guitar’s tessitura and helpsmy vocal fatigue. If you’ve never tried it, you should!

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - not wishing to labour the point, but you seem to agree that where the majority of (higher or lower) notes are in a piece is its tessitura. It's where they are in *the piece* rather than where they are on what's playing them - although generally speaking, tessitura is related to voice. Yes. it's very different from *range*, which is exactly what any *instrument* will have.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons different songs are in different keys is due to the range of each song - its highest and lowest notes. Two songs could both be in the same key, but their highest and lowest notes needn't be the same. Or, two songs could have the same highest or lowest note, but each be in a different key.

So, with a vocal range of over two octaves, which isn't bad, you're going to have to find a suitable key for each and every different song. Yes, there will be songs that have a small range, and these are easier to accommodate. That's because moving them up or down by a couple of tones will still keep them within *your* vocal range. There will also be songs which might take you too high, so you change to a lower key in order to keep the high notes happy, but that then takes you down too low. Maybe those songs are just not for you.

If you can't already, get so you can play in any key. Then you'll be able to try out a song, realise it's too high/low, and adjust accordingly. You should fing just about every song will have its 'best' key for your voice, but you alone need to find it. That's what good singer/guitarists do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually transposing the guitar chords, or trying to sing 'high octave' or 'low octave' to the same chords?   I'm afraid the right place for your voice is almost always going to be somewhere in-between!     If the song is a Blues in F - F7, F7, Bb7, F7, C7, Bb7, F7 - maybe for YOU it will have to be a Blues in C - C7, C7, F7, C7, G7, F7, C7.     Get those transposing chops working!